# Array List to Export Data to Excel Convert to Decimal from String

Tags: c#, arrays, export-to-excel

```
gvar.gintDGRow = 0;
gvar.gintOrd = 0;
string[,] strCanvass = new string[99999, 13];
string strLastRow;
Excel2.Application oXL;
Excel2._Workbook oWB;
Excel2._Worksheet oSheet;
Excel2.Range oRng;



for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {

                    if (DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString() != "")
                    {

                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 0] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 1] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 2] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 3] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 4] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 5] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 6] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 7] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 8] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 9] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 10] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                            strCanvass[gvar.gintDGRow, 11] = DataGridView1.Rows[gvar.gintDGRow].Cells[12].Value.ToString();              
                    }


                    gvar.gintDGRow++;

                }

                strLastRow = "L" + Convert.ToString(gvar.gintDGRow +1 );



oXL = new Excel2.Application();
                oXL.Visible = true;

                //Get a new workbook.
                oWB = (Excel2._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
                oSheet = (Excel2._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

                //Add table headers going cell by cell.
                oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "RR Date";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "RR No.";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "DR/SI";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "P.O. No.";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Vendor ID";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "Vendor Name";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "Van No.";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "Item Code";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 9] = "Description";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 10] = "U of M.";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 11] = "Qty Recv.";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 12] = "Unit Cost";

                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "L1").Font.Bold = true;
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "L1").VerticalAlignment =
                Excel2.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;


                // Create an array to multiple values at once.

                for (int x = 0; x < strCanvass.Length; x++) 
                {
                Convert.ToDecimal(strCanvass[x, 11]);
                oSheet.get_Range("A2", strLastRow).Value2 = strCanvass;
                }    
                oXL.Visible = true;
                oXL.UserControl = true;
```

i have a datagrid list of data with a 12 columns insert into an array i made and called out back that array to export the data to excel only the 11 column needs to be convert to decimal in order to be sum up. i tried converting it but it doesn't sum up on the excel in order to be sum it needs to be on the right side to be sum but when i export it its on the left side which is unable to be sum up. can anyone help me with this i don't understand it well sorry..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make your cell datatype equal to DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number.

```
cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number;
```